# Connect mySQL via SSH error 2002

Tags: mysql, c, ssh

I'm trying to connect to my mySQL server with the C interface via a SSH tunnel.

What I currently do is open the SSH tunnel :

```
ssh user@IP -L 10293:127.0.0.1:3306
```

And then in code :

```
    MYSQL *conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "username", "password", "production", 10293, NULL, 0);

    unsigned int error = mysql_errno(conn);
```

I get the error 2002 just after having connecting. Error 2002 is "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket". However, why is it trying to connect via socket when I didn't specify any socket in the connection?

What else could possibly go wrong?

Username, password and table name have been checked multiple times of course.

Comment: It's telling you basically it cannot connect. Sockets are used everywhere: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_socket 
My guess is that you do not have enough privileges to connect to the MySQL host.

Comment: Ha thanks, got it. I needed to specify "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" since I was binding to that IP and the actual localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to specify "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" as the address since I was binding the IP itself, and not the actually localhost.